# error calling metod and/or action controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, action

i have this problem:
I should decrement an attribute "quantity" of a line_item.
So i created a button_to to do this.
The problem is that even if i created the new action "less" in the controller of line_item and added it in the routes , my function doesn't work. 
Can you tell me what is the problem?

Routes.rb

```
resources :line_items do
    post :less, on: :collection     
end
```

Line_item Controller
In this file i include the set_cart method (it works) so i have the possibility to use @cart vaiable
i wrote before_action :set_cart, only: [:create,:less]

```
def less
    puts "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
    #Rails sa di dover prendere l' ID da product per eseguire il find :D
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    #aggiungiamo un prodotto in piu'
    #ritorna un current_item
    @line_item = @cart.less_items(product.id)
respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_url}
            #a respond_to passiamo il blocco con la @current_item
            #si passa un blocco perchè è definito cosi il metodo
            format.js   { @current_item = @line_item} 
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

cart model:

```
def less_items(product_id)  
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item && current_item > 1
        current_item.quantity -= 1
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
end
```

The console say to me:

[image: Console]

NEW PROBLEM:

Thx to  Tomáš Dundáček i understand that i had to edit the cancan ability file to permits to the less method to pass. Now i still have problem. Here the picture:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are redirected from some `before_action`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as an answer to the new problem:

This line:

```
if current_item && current_item > 1
```

needs to be changed to

```
if current_item && current_item.quantity > 1
```

Comment: i edit it a second before your answer :p Now if i recharge the page i see the modify. But my Ajax doesn't work.. arrgg  Maybe i have to create a new js file for the less...

Comment: YES I created new file less.js  and it works .Thx Tomáš Dundáček. Love you!

Answer (score 0):

Don t think , but i have these:

```
include CurrentCart
before_action :set_cart, only: [:create,:less]    
before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
#cancan
load_and_authorize_resource
```

Comment: yes, most probably it is cancan who is redirecting you away... also, please try to answer with comments, or in edits to your original question rather than with an answer

Comment: the best thing you can do is try to put a `puts` into `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` in your ApplicationController to see if it's it

Comment: i put the ability in cancan for the action less. Now i see the puts and also i see that it enters in the method of the car. i ll show u the image , but i have still problem.  
 [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KvAQB.png

Comment: ok, so please update the original question with the new problem :-)